# how to skip before_save filter in Rails for specific command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a before_save defined as follows:

```
  def before_save
    self.token = generate_token
  end
```

I want to skip it for specific save method calls. so in my code I would like to do

```
@user.save
```

without before_save filter getting called. Can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do:

```
 @user.send(:update_without_callbacks)
```

Or create_without_callbacks works as well. I have used both but I don't know if there is a "save_without_callbacks" 
Either way, use sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also include conditional logic in your method to handle the cases where you wouldn't want the callback to fire.

```
def before_save
  self.token = generate_token if token.blank?
end
```

Not a great example, but you get the idea.